# Check if object is a jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a fast way of checking if an object is a jQuery object or a native JavaScript object?

example:

```
var o = {};
var e = $('#element');

function doStuff(o) {
    if (o.selector) {
        console.log('object is jQuery');
    }
}

doStuff(o);
doStuff(e);
```

obviously, the code above works but it's not safe. You could potentially add a selector key to the `o` object and get the same result. Is there a better way of making sure that the object actually is a jQuery object?

Something in line with `(typeof obj == 'jquery')`

Comment: As of jQuery 3.0 this is definitely not a correct way to check for an object being a jQuery object because the `selector` property was deprecated long ago and removed in 3.0. Even in earlier versions, a jQuery object can have an empty selector string, for example `$(window)` has no selector. Use `instanceof` instead.

Answer (score 948, accepted):

You can use the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator:

```
if (obj instanceof jQuery){
    console.log('object is jQuery');
}
```

**Explanation**: the `jQuery` function (aka `$`) is implemented as a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor). Constructor functions are to be called with the `new` prefix.

When you call `$(foo)`, internally jQuery translates this to `new jQuery(foo)`<sup>1</sup>. JavaScript proceeds to initialize `this` inside the constructor function to point to a new instance of `jQuery`, setting it's properties to those found on `jQuery.prototype` (aka `jQuery.fn`). Thus, you get a `new` object where `instanceof jQuery` is `true`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's actually `new jQuery.prototype.init(foo)`: the constructor logic has been offloaded to another constructor function called `init`, but the concept is the same.</sub>

Comment: So do you mean `if (obj instanceof jQuery){...}`?

Comment: @NigelAngel: Yup, that's what he means :)

Comment: This doesn't work in case of multiple jQuery instances on a page.

Comment: @Georgiy Ivankin: you're telling me multiple jquery script includes on a page break the `instanceof` JavaScript operator? Or did you fail to capture the essense of the answer: that `instanceof jQuery1` , `instanceof jQuery2`, etc work to answer the OPs question?

Comment: @CrescentFresh I mean if I have $ in my current namespace pointing to jQuery2 and I have an object from outer namespace (where $ is jQuery1) than I have no way to use instanceof for checking if this object is a jQuery object.

Comment: If you're not sure whether jQuery is loaded at the time of the if statement, you can extend the check to be `typeof jQuery === 'function' && obj instanceof jQuery` since `jQuery` does not have to be declared in order for the `typeof` operator to work without throwing an error.

Comment: Certainly an edge case here but doing `$(342)` returns a JQuery object, and has length ([342]), but technically is not a valid JQuery object as the API will not work on it. (e.g. $(342).height())

Comment: This does not work in an npm package that does not declare `jquery` as a dependency.

Comment: Checking for an element NOT being jQuery is `if(!(obj instanceof jQuery))`. The double parentheses are needed, not sure why. Leaving out the inner parentheses (like this: `if(!obj instanceof jQuery)`) returns `false` every time.

Answer (score 116):

You may also use the .jquery property as described here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/

```
var a = { what: "A regular JS object" },
b = $('body');

if ( a.jquery ) { // falsy, since it's undefined
    alert(' a is a jQuery object! ');    
}

if ( b.jquery ) { // truthy, since it's a string
    alert(' b is a jQuery object! ');
}
```

Comment: As [David](http://stackoverflow.com/users/210578/david) pointed out in the question, checking a property of a variable who's value could be null (i.e. if "a" or "b" were null) is not safe (it will throw a TypeError). Using "b instanceof jQuery" is better.

Comment: This way works if jQuery is not loaded, whereas `b instanceof jQuery` throws a ReferenceError if jQuery isn’t available on the page. Both approaches are useful in different cases.

Comment: More efficient maybe, but still not safe. It may require `try ... catch`, particularly in oldIE.

Comment: In cases where it's possible that jQuery is not loaded, you can use `if ((typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') && (obj instanceof jQuery)) {...`

Comment: That's not such a good example.. more likely `a` would be a DOM node, like `document.body` and then, theoretically there is a chance the `jquery` key somehow came to be ontop of that node's chain.

Comment: Let's say you want to write a function that accepts both Element and jQuery objects to be passed. `instanceof` requires your library to take a dependency to jQuery while checking the `jquery` property doesn't. I prefer to check `jquery` and treat the object like any array-like type if it exists. This way you don't force the clients of your library to have jQuery as a dependency while allowing the ones that do to pass their jQuery objects and expect your function work.

Answer (score 32):

Check out the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Instanceof_Operator) operator.

```
var isJqueryObject = obj instanceof jQuery
```

Answer (score 26):

The best way to check the instance of an object is through **[instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator** or with the method [isPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isPrototypeOf) which inspects if the prototype of an object is in another object's prototype chain.

```js
obj instanceof jQuery;
jQuery.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj);
```

But sometimes it might fail in the case of multiple jQuery instances on a document. As @Georgiy Ivankin mentioned:

> *if I have `$` in my current namespace pointing to `jQuery2` and I have an object from outer namespace (where `$` is `jQuery1`) then I have no way to use `instanceof` for checking if that object is a `jQuery` object*

One way to overcome that problem is by aliasing the jQuery object in a **[closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)** or **[IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)**

```js
//aliases jQuery as $
(function($, undefined) {
    /*... your code */

    console.log(obj instanceof $);
    console.log($.prototype.isPrototypeOf(obj));

    /*... your code */
}(jQuery1));
//imports jQuery1
```

Other way to overcome that problem is by inquiring the `jquery` property in `obj`

```js
'jquery' in obj
```

However, if you try to perform that checking with primitive values, it will throw an error, so you can modify the previous checking by ensuring `obj` to be an `Object`

```js
'jquery' in Object(obj)
```

Although the previous way is not the safest (you can create the `'jquery'` property in an object), we can improve the validation by working with both approaches:

```js
if (obj instanceof jQuery || 'jquery' in Object(obj)) { }
```

The problem here is that any object can define a property `jquery` as own, so a better approach would be to ask in the prototype, and ensure that the object is not `null` or `undefined`

```js
if (obj && (obj instanceof jQuery || obj.constructor.prototype.jquery)) { }
```

Due to **coercion**, the `if` statement will make short circuit by evaluating the `&&` operator when `obj` is any of the ***falsy*** values (`null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `""`), and then proceeds to perform the other validations.

Finally we can write an utility function:

```js
function isjQuery(obj) {
  return (obj && (obj instanceof jQuery || obj.constructor.prototype.jquery));
}
```

---

Let's take a look at: [Logical Operators and truthy / falsy](http://nfriedly.com/techblog/2009/07/advanced-javascript-operators-and-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: How does that improve safety, though? Non-jQuery objects with a jquery property would still be misdetected. I don't see what else using both approaches might "improve", either.

Comment: this is a easy way to check whether an object is a jQuery object, if for any reason you suspect that someone is creating objects with properties such as _jquery_, then you can  create a validator more robust, i.e. checking for properties in the _prototype:_ ***myObj.constructor.prototype.jquery*** or better yet, you can use the function ***[Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/IsPrototypeOf)***

Comment: If you `||` any of that with a `'jquery' in Object(obj)`, though, it goes to drain, because it won't prevent non-jQuery objects with that property from passing the verification. I do believe checking for that property in the prototype improves the situation, though. Maybe you should add that to your answer! I don't think any other answer here mentions that possibility :)

Comment: isn't `obj.__proto__.jquery` instead of `obj.constructor.prototype.jquery` enough? just a bit short :)

Comment: @Axel yes, it works too :). I used `constructor.prototype` because `obj` is supposed to be an instance of the constructor, that is `jQuery`. On the other hand `__proto__` is available for any kind of object.

Answer (score 5):

For those who want to know if an object is a jQuery object without having jQuery installed, the following snippet should do the work :

```
function isJQuery(obj) {
  // All jQuery objects have an attribute that contains the jQuery version.
  return typeof obj === "object" && obj != null && obj.jquery != null;
}
```

Comment: The `&& obj &&` is to check if obj is not `null`, because `typeof null` returns 'object' too. It could be `obj !== null`, but this is correct too.

Comment: @NunoRafaelFigueiredo Updated my seven years old answer, taking your remark in consideration, and improving comparison with `obj != null` which is better since it also excludes `undefined`.

Answer (score 4):

However, There is one more way to check the object in jQuery.

```
jQuery.type(a); //this returns type of variable.
```

I have made example to understand things, [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/8rx7wk17/2/)

Answer (score 3):

```
return el instanceof jQuery ? el.size() > 0 : (el && el.tagName);
```

Comment: To check for a DOM element, better use `nodeType` property, and to ensure a `boolean` value be returned, you can use double negation `!!(el && el.nodeType)`

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the object is produced by JQuery with the `jquery` property:

```
myObject.jquery // 3.3.1
```

=> return the number of the JQuery version if the object produced by JQuery.
=> otherwise, it returns `undefined`

Answer (score -9):

```
var elArray = [];
var elObjeto = {};

elArray.constructor == Array //TRUE
elArray.constructor == Object//TALSE

elObjeto.constructor == Array//FALSE
elObjeto.constructor == Object//TRUE
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are rarely useful. Please consider adding some context to your answer.