# What JavaScript framework is the least evil?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

I'm not a huge fan of the JavaScript frameworks that are out there today. I think a lot of the libraries could be written better, are chosen for a project because of favoritism rather than understanding the requirements of the problem at hand, and some JavaScript developers come to depend on them too much to the point where they are jQuery or dojo programmers, not *JavaScript* programmers. Alas, that is one person's opinion and the fact is JavaScript frameworks are a part of life. So, here's a new take on an old question: Which JavaScript framework is the least evil? That is to say, **which library most closely adheres to best practices?** Considering jQuery for a moment, it employs browser sniffing and doesn't use `new` for constructors. It is very popular and some may judge it the best by some standard, it disregards what has come to be accepted as best practices in those cases.

Edit: Please just don't say jQuery or YUI or dojo or whatever. Please say which but also provide examples.

Comment: @Timothy `I think a lot of the libraries could be written better` - write one then we're all gonna be happy

Comment: @Timothy, I like jQuery - but that's only because it has a good user-base and community behind it. Making it less evil than say... YUI :)

Comment: @Timothy - "I think a lot of the libraries could be written better" majority of open source projects are started with this statement

Comment: jQuery does *not* use browser sniffing but rather provides support for *developers* to employ browser sniffing if they so choose (see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/). Also, jQuery is itself implemented as a constructor function (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object/1853246#1853246 , ie it *does* use `new`).

Comment: Please define "best practices"

Comment: jQuery provides browser-sniffing, but advises you not to use it. Internally it uses only feature-sniffing. And it doesn't really have any objecty stuff for which `new` would be appropriate. So I don't think these are good reasons to hate on jQuery.

Comment: ...no, far better reasons would be its far-too-overloaded interfaces (making it hard to read and determine which method is being used possibly-by-accident), its confusing mixture of chain-style methods (so you're never quite sure whether you're getting a returned object or the original), the lack of a select-one method (so you only have select-many, which won't generate an error when your selector fails to match anything), its encouragment of string-hacking selectors and HTML, and in particular its own appalling string-hacking in anything to do with HTML handling, through the `clean` function.

Comment: I've never found a framework that isn't to some extent evil – Prototype 1.x is just as bad as jQuery, though in different ways – and I'm not convinced it's possible to make a framework non-evil. The nature of JavaScript and the DOM makes it difficult to add features in a clean way. And hell, plain JavaScript itself is pretty evil to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lol. That surely is subjective, but anyways...

Personally I think [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) is the least *evil* as it has [Douglas Crockford](http://crockfordfacts.com/) himself advocating it. ('nuf said)

Although, I don't really think that other frameworks are necessarily evil...

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) seems to go for easiness of use (just include jquery.js, copy-paste some samples, hack a little bit and you're done).

Dojo goes for completeness (for what I can see) implementing many utilities (much like [apache commons](http://commons.apache.org/) for java), and a broad list of widgets, grids and charts.

Then there's [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) which I'm not really fond of it since it modifies the native objects.

There's also [Ext JS](http://extjs.com/) that has lots of widgets and visual components to build full fledge applications, but I'd [stay away](http://codemonkeyism.com/more-on-extjs-the-gpl-fiasco-and-open-source-community-style/)...

Comment: Ext JS is now [GPLv3-licensed](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/licensing/, and there is no longer an open source controversy.

Comment: The codemonkeyism link is broken

Answer (score 6):

Well - I used to be of the same view, never really used JS libs as - well, I can do it myself. But in my job I was forced to use Jquery.

Previously to that I would use Prototype and script.aculo.us and liked it because of its minimal injection into your daily workflow.

But saying the libs are evil isn't really something I agree with. Looking at the code of many libs, they are well written and concise. They generally fit all browsers without bugs.

That's the real reason to pick up these frameworks - to implement code you could create, only better. I would never be as bold to state, I could do as thorough a job as 100 contributor the frameworks have.

Additionally, its the amount of time these JS libs swallow for you. 
If I can shave 3 days off creation and debugging of a project - because someone has happily done the exact same thing for me, that's great! Then hopefully I can give back on day.

I don't believe there are evil frameworks, just different.

Answer (score -1):

My vote is for jquery.  With noConflict() you can use multiple versions on the same page, easy learning curve with css selectors.

Comment: did you even read the question?

Answer (score -2):

[MyLibrary](http://www.cinsoft.net/mylib.html)

Comment: It calls itself an "Ajax library". I wish there was a -1 button for websites

Comment: A) It doesn't. It says its a "browser scripting library (also known as an Ajax library)" referring to the fact that many people (who don't know better) consider "JavaScript library" and "Ajax library" to be the same. And as with many frameworks Ajax is only a small part that can be left out if not needed. And B) What is so bad about "Ajax library"?

Comment: "Ajax" has come to mean a dozen different things, mostly due to mis/overuse. I prefer to avoid the term altogether. Let's leave buzzwords for marketing.

Comment: I completely agree with you. And IMHO the wording on the site, the structure of the library and the presence of the builder acknowledges exactly that.