# How do I check if a variable is a jQuery object or plain DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I check if a variable is a jQuery object or plain DOM element?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object

Answer (score 41, accepted):

- A jquery object has a `jquery` property.
- A jquery object is an `instanceof jQuery` ([`instanceof` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof))
- A DOM element has a `nodeType` property