# Check if jQuery object is a variable or Dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object, dom

I am writing a plugin and have a question. Take these two lines into consideration

```
$('target').myPlugin();

var myVar = $('target').myPlugin();
```

Since the second target is not yet in the DOM, there is some functions I would have to change in my plugin to achieve my goals. Yet, those changes may cause the plugin to fail on the first target.

Simply, I am looking for a way (if it is even possible) to determine in my plugin if the target element is already in the DOM or in a variable.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

To expound a bit...

Take this example, why does this not work?

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>');
var newInput = $('<input/>').wrap(wrapper);
$('#newDiv').append(newInput);
```

Because the input does not actually exist yet...

Comment: var myVar= typeof element == 'object' ? element : document.getElementById(element);

Comment: Both of the statements you've written will look for `target` in the DOM (unless in one of them `target` is an HTML string). Your plugin can't distinguish between the two lines you have written, because they both do the same thing (one of them just happens to assigns a variable afterwards). Could you expand?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426116/how-do-i-check-if-a-variable-is-a-jquery-object-or-plain-dom-element

Comment: @GirishSakhare That is not my question...

Comment: `yourVariable.closest(document).length` will tell you if the element is in the DOM or not.

Comment: @Shai I Expanded a bit in my original question to show an example of when a certain function like `.wrap()` breaks when used on an object within a variable. When I asked a question a while back about why it broke, everyone said it's because the input was not actually in the DOM yet and was stored within jQuery until it is actually appended.