# How can I tell if a variable is wrapped in jQuery or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that has the signature of:

```
function(id,target){
 //do stuff
}
```

The target parameter is assumed to be a jQuery wrapped object however it is possible that it could be a dom element in which case I'd like to wrap it in jQuery before I do operations on it.  How can I test the target variable for jQuery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if object is a jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)

Comment: you can also check the length of the variable. if it has a length defined as 0 then it's jquery. if the length is undefined then it's dom.

Comment: @scrappedcola Probably a bad idea, as arrays are not jQuery objects.

Comment: Richard, thanks for pointing that out.  When I did my initial research I used "variable" in my search which didn't turn up any relevant results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!(target instanceof jQuery)) {
  target = jQuery(target);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `instanceof`

```
obj instanceof jQuery
```

[Check if object is a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)