# How to know an object is jQuery object or not

Tags: jquery

I have created a  function which tells whether a variable hold jQuery object or on is there any substitute of this. Below is my code

```
/*Is there any substitute of this function*/

function iSJqueryObj(elm)
{
    return elm && jQuery.isFunction(elm.html);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kE7Lp/3/

Comment: Duplicate of **[Check if object is a jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223)**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if object is a jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
console.log(elm instanceof jQuery);
```

or:

```
console.log(elm instanceof $);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/8jUKX/

Answer (score 3):

Try the **instance of**

```
obj instanceof jQuery
```

Comment: yeah whatsoever :D I was first but edited it but its not that important :D