# Check if obect is jQuery wrapper

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Check if object is a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)

I need something like:

```
function func(obj) {
    if (!$.isJQ(obj)) {
        obj = $(obj);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Is there any `isJQ` function in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the instanceof operator:

```
obj instanceof jQuery
```

So, your code goes like :

```
function func(obj) {
    if (!(obj instanceof jQuery)) {
        obj = $(obj);
    }
    // ...
}
```