# Check if 'this' is $(this) or just plain old 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one function:

```
function myFunction(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
}
```

Now sometimes, myFunction gets called with $(this) as the context but sometimes the context is just 'this'.

In one line how can I do something similar to this:

```
if(this == $(this)){
var e = $(this);
}
```

Basically a test to see if 'this' is a jQuery 'this' or a JS 'this'.

Possible?

Comment: It probably won't blow up if you do a `$(this)` either way.

Comment: And it doesn't really matter.  This is valid `$($($($($($($(this))))))) `.  And I'm 99% sure jQuery will check for you and not do the extra work if it's already a jQuery object.

Comment: Consider having a convention about the type of the context of that function. If you have a jQuery object, you can access the DOM element with `[0]`.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object

Comment: and by the way, you are wrong in saying: `Basically a test to see if 'this' is a jQuery 'this' or a JS 'this'`....conceptual error or maybe you might want to word it the other way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
if (this.jquery) { // refers to jQuery version
  // jQuery object
}
```

Alternatively:

```
if (this instanceof jQuery) { // prototype chain
  // jQuery object
}
```

However, as others have said, it doesn't really matter, `$(this)` will work whether or not `this` is already a `jQuery` object or a DOM element.

Comment: However, I don't think it's worth checking if you're just going to pass it to `$()` anyhow as it will do the check for you.

Comment: `var obj = {jquery:1};` TROLOLOLO... `:P`

Comment: Would the performance difference between doing João's version, and merely wrapping the 'this' context in jQuery ($thisContext = $(this);) ever be significant? Is there any reason (other than explicitly wanting, or not wanting, a jQuery object) one would prefer one method over another?

Comment: @Teeg The performance penalty of evaluating the expression `$(this)` is a few micro-seconds (millionths of seconds), which means that it's negligible. You can safely have a few dozens of `$(this)`, `$(window)`, etc. expressions within one function invocation without hurting performance.

Comment: @Sime Vidas I had a feeling that would be the case. Joao's answer makes a lot of sense and is good, but for most of the cases I've encountered, I've tended to just wrap $(this).

Comment: @Teeg: I agree with you, I've actually added that suggestion in my answer, even though the question asked explicitly for a way to detect a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

You can also just do `var e = $(this)` when `this` is a jQuery object or if it's not.

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with it would just be to always wrap it in `$(...)`.  Wrapping a jQuery object like that creates a clone (see the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#cloning-jquery-objects)), so this HTML:

```
<a href="test" id="​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​test-link">Test Link</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

with this JS:

```
​var link = $('#test-link');
var doubleWrappedLink = $(link);

alert(doubleWrappedLink.attr('href'));​​​​​​​
```

will correctly pop up "test".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet:

```
if (obj instanceof jQuery || 'jquery' in Object(obj)) { }
```

Take a look at: **[Check if object is a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25004941/2247494)**