# How can I know if I'm calling a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I've some libraries on my website, that are using $ as variable/function. I made them separate with :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    codeThatWillUseJquery($);
});
```

but in fact, I think there are somethings wrong. in fact :

```
function codeThatWillUseJquery($)
{
    console.log($('#myId').index());
}
```

it returns always -1, on every element. So I think there is some incompatibility in the code.

How can I know if `$('#myId').index()` call the jQuery's .index() function? Is there a way?

Comment: Why not do something like `var $jq = jQuery.noConflict()` if there is another `$`-namespace?

Comment: go to jQuery Source File watch the .index() function than type on Chrome Console $('#myId').index() without ; and compare snipets.

Comment: $('#myId').index() returns TypeError: undefined is not a function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use `obj instanceof jQuery`

please check this [Check if object is a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)

Comment: uhm, so `$('#myId').index() instanceof jQuery`? It returns false :O

Comment: like `$('#myId') instanceof jQuery`