# how to check a parameter passed in a function is a string or an element?

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can i pass two different type of value in a single function which accepts single parameter.

let a function is `function a(b){return c;}`

i'm trying to pass a string while calling the function `a` some places like `a('a string value')` then i'll do something with it. Now i need to pass a html element like `a(jquery('#someDiv'))` and then i'll some another stuff. I need to differentiate both in the function declaration.

Any idea from the experts?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I was looking for a tip to check the data type i'm going to pass as the parameter of the function `a`. It can be a string or a number or an object or even a function. I don't want to use a fallback. I want to use the last else statement to through an error or exception.

Comment: if(typeof(b) == 'string'){....}

Comment: `if (typeof b === "string") { /* Holy cow, it's a string */ } else { /* Maybe its a jQuery object */ };`

Comment: `jquery('#someDiv')` returns a jQuery object, not an HTML element.

Comment: [Docs for `typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). Note that `typeof jQuery('div')` will be `'object'`.

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate

Comment: you can usually get away with a simple duck type: b.split ? str : obj ;

Comment: Thanks everyone for your effort. What i really am looking for is a tip to distinguish the types of a javascript variable. Here i gave the example using a string and a jquery object. but i want my function to be able to receive any kind of data types. maybe there can be string or number or some html element or some object even some function. I was seeking for a tip to determine any one of them explicitly. But I don't know why and how i'm ended up as a duplicated question. Maybe i didn't explained it in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator can be used to test for strings.

```
if (typeof b == 'string') {
    //handle string
}
```

The second part is a bit more tricky. `typeof` will return `object` for a jQuery object. I believe it is safe enough to check if the object's `[[Prototype]]` is the same as the jQuery constructor's prototype using [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

```
else if (Object.getPrototypeOf(b) === $.fn) {
    //it is an object that inherits from the jQuery prototype
}
```

But that isn't supported in IE<9. If a fallback is necessary, [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) will have a similar effect and can be used instead of `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```
else if (b instanceof jQuery) {}
```

So a complete solution with old IE support:

```
if (typeof b == 'string') {
    //handle string
} else if (b instanceof jQuery) {
    //handle jQuery object
} else {
    throw 'Invalid argument';
}
```

---

* Note that `instanceof` will return `true` even when a constructor "subclasses" jQuery (has a link in the prototype chain to jQuery), while `Object.getPrototypeOf` will only return `true` if the object's internal `[[Prototype]]` points to the same object as the jQuery constructor's prototype. It is rather rare when this will make a difference, but worth keeping in mind.

Nevertheless of these small quirks, this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object) has `instanceof` as the accepted answer, as it is the most compatible solution.

And to explain a couple things, `jQuery` itself is not a constructor, but its prototype object is shared with `jQuery.fn.init` which is the actual constructor, and `jQuery.fn` is a shorthand for `jQuery.prototype`, so:

```
jQuery.fn.init.prototype === jQuery.prototype
jQuery.prototype === jQuery.fn
```

This is going a little off-topic already, so here's a more in-depth article for the interested readers: [How jQuery instantiates objects as jQuery.fn.init, and what that means if you want to subclass jQuery](http://blog.quickui.org/2012/06/07/jquery-fn-init/)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Its very close to the tip i'm looking for. I've edited my question. I hope you'll understand my question once again. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you will have to add a couple more `else if` branches for `typeof b == 'function'` and `typeof b == 'number'`. Either that or do you want to simply identify the kind of object? I fear the latter may not be possible for objects without having constructors/prototypes to test against.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've tried this and the the result is current. Thanks a lot for your co-operation.