# How to check if an object is a jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

> Related: [Check if object is a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)

I have an object `x`, and after running `console.log(x)` Chrome's debugger shows me this:

[image]

How can I check if `x` is a `jQuery.Event` using JavaScript? (I've tried `Object.getPrototypeOf`, `toString` and `obj.constructor`).

Comment: `x instanceof jQuery.Event`?

Comment: awesome, thanks! Is there any way to get the string "jquery.Event" just from the object?

Comment: Why do you need it as a string?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Can't think of a reason right now, was just curious.

Comment: @Ian - Why did you re-open this?

Comment: @j08691 It might sound silly, but I felt the question was different enough, specifically because it refers to the jQuery **event** object. It turns out that the answer is fundamentally the same as the duplicate you linked, but the question was about something different (although **quite close**). I don't know, I just feel like it isn't right for someone searching for this question to be redirected to a duplicate with an answer for something else. I'd hope they'd be able to figure out that `instanceof` should be applied in the same way, but it's possible they wouldn't. I don't know, I'm picky

Comment: fwiw I was aware of `instanceof` and it was non-obvious that this could be used on "subclasses" of the main jQuery export.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agreeing @Rocket's comment: `instanceof` is the way to go. You can try this on SO's website in the JS console

```
var x = $.Event()
x instanceof $.Event
```

More information can be found in this eerily similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1853246/1883547