# Using jQuery object understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I had to jump into jQuery development without getting too much time into learning all the associated basics, so there is one thing that throws me off quite a bit.

I see two different ways our developers access jQuery objects:

**Case 1:**

```
var container =  $("#containerId");

// Then use it as:
container.hide();
```

**Case 2:**

```
var container =  $("#containerId");

// Then use it as:
$(container).hide();
```

From my thin up to date knowledge, by wrapping a container as in `var obj = $(container)`, we get a jQuery object `obj` that we can further work with.

But then why do I see intermittently developers wrapping it again when using as in `$(obj).doSomething()`?

***Edit:*** the question suggested as duplicate is asking about best practices and although similar, my question is purely on understanding of jQuery object wrapping.

Comment: Case two is redundant

Comment: You see that because either (a) they are unsure at that point in the code if it is a jQuery object or a selector (sometimes for example a function argument may be unknown whether it's a jQuery object or a selector), or (b) because they don't know any better.

Comment: Perhaps they're mistaking `obj` for a dom object, and not a jquery one? It's generally considered good practice to prefix jquery objects with a dollar to indicate that they are indeed jquery objects

Comment: As said @MysterX is redundant, and most developers make that because they don't identify the jQuerized objects. Affortunately, jQuery knows that and when it receives a jquery object it ignores the re-declaration

Comment: Probably more than one dev had their hands in the code - and one of them made a syntax error. Case 2 is redundant. Typiclly when someone wants to make (and denote) a DOM node as a jQuery object you would see something like this:

`var $foo = $(".foo");`

That way, when someone comes along later to update the code, they can immediately tell that $foo is a jQuery object and not a variable or something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Second wrapping does nothing as I remember. So if there can be a selector a dom element or a jQuery object you can just wrap it and do not care about what it was.

But if you know it is a jquery object, you shouldn't use wrapping.

Comment: None of the answers with code in them will catch all cases where people rightfully or wrongly wrap existing jQuery objects. This is the best answer to OP question. The *"why"* part of question is often a mystery that will never be known

Answer (score 3):

When developers develop a function, for example in a jQuery plugin, that can get a parameter that is either a DOM element or a jQuery object or a selector, then they use it:

```
function x(container) {
    container = $(container);
    // use container as a jquery object
}

// these both work:
x("#containerId");
x($("#containerId"));
x(document.getElementById("containerId"));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Case 1:**
Using a jQuery selector to find a dom element and return a jQuery object:

```
var container =  $("#containerId");

// Then use it as:
container.hide();
```

**Case 2: Redundant/mistake (or perhaps if you're unsure if a variable is already a jQuery object but you need it to be):**
Using a jQuery selector to find a dom element and return a jQuery object then pass it to a new jQuery object:

```
var container =  $("#containerId");

// Then use it as:
$(container).hide();
```

**Case 3:**
Select a dom element then use it in constructor for a new jQuery object (on which you then call hide() )

```
var container =  document.getElementById("#containerId");

// Then use it as:
$(container).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Case 2 creates a jQuery object from an existing jQuery object, which is unnecessary.

$ is an alias for the jQuery [Selector function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/). The function can take a few different arguments, such as...

1. A string: `var container =  $("#containerId");`
2. An html element: `var document = $(document);`
3. A jQuery element: `var container = $($("#containerId"))`

In the 3rd example, the 2nd call to the Selector function works, but it unnessesary.

Answer (score 0):

`Case 1` is always preferred.  Always cache and reuse `jQuery` objects if possible.  This will give the best performance.

`Case 2` is the easiest way to ensure you're working with a jQuery object.  There are better ways, which you can see [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object). I would never recommend selecting objects like this.  If I was expecting a jQuery object, I would do this instead.
e.g.

```
function hideContainer(container)
{
    if(!(container instanceof jQuery))
    {
         container =  $("#containerId");
    }

    container.hide();
}
```

It's actually faster to select the object again via the selector string (instead of using the object reference), since it doesn't have to access object properties to determine the selector.

[Take a look at these jsPerf test cases](http://jsperf.com/caching-jquery-objects-perf/30) and you will see that `Case 2` is much slower than `Case 1` (it was 40% slower in my case, on Chrome).

But again, I think `Case 2` is just the easiest, quickest way to ensure you  have a `jQuery` object; which is why you see it so often.