# How jQuery distinguish between 'data' and 'selector' parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

in jQuery function:
`.on(event, [selector,] [data,] handler)`

How jQuery parse this call:
`on('click', 'tag3', () => {})`
`tag3` is **selector** or **data**?

Comment: Use the source, luke! https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/58c6ca9822afa42d3b40cca8edb0abe90a2bcb34/src/event.js#L36

Comment: selector is a string or jquery/DOM object, data is plain object.

Comment: What is importance of knowing how as long as you follow docs in using method appropriately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument must be the handler. So if there are two arguments there there is no `data` and no `selector`.

If there are four arguments than the second one must be `selector` and the third one must be `data`.

So it only becomes tricky if there are exactly three arguments.

If the second argument isn't a string, then it can't be a selector, so it must be data.

If it is a string then it could be a selector or data. Now jQuery could do some heuristics by running it through the selector engine and seeing if it is a valid selector … but it doesn't. It just assumes that if the second argument is a string then it is a selector.

Answer (score 0):

> **How jQuery distinguish between 'data' and 'selector' parameter?**

They have a different data-types

**data**  - is a plain object (not a DOM or jquery object)

**selector** - is a string or a jquery/DOM/DOM-array object.

so, jquery can make out whether an argument is a selector or data by judging the properties of the argument, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384286/javascript-isdom-how-do-you-check-if-a-javascript-object-is-a-dom-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)

```
return obj instanceof HTMLElement; //to check if it is a DOM object
```

or

```
return obj instanceof jQuery; //to check if it is a jquery object
```

> **tag3 is selector or data?**

As per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-ownerDocument)

> If a string is passed as the parameter to $(), jQuery examines the
>   string to see if it looks like HTML (i.e., it starts with ).
>   If not, the string is interpreted as a selector expression, as
>   explained above. But if the string appears to be an HTML snippet,
>   jQuery attempts to create new DOM elements as described by the HTML.
>   Then a jQuery object is created and returned that refers to these
>   elements.

If the string passed to jquery method is an HTML then subsequent object is either a `document` (DOM object) or an attributes object.

Comment: "If a string is passed as the parameter to $()," — The question is asking about `on()` not `$()`.

Comment: @Quentin oh, my bad. Anyways, upper half of the answer is still valid. `on()` also checks for the `typeof` argument value https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/58c6ca9822afa42d3b40cca8edb0abe90a2bcb34/src/event.js#L43

Comment: Anyway, guys, thanks! I found out in source code, that it checks what if it 'string', so it's selector. If not - data