# How to apply a type guard for jQuery instance?

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm trying to apply a type guard for a variable which might be a jQuery instance. However, as `JQuery` is an interface from `jquery.d.ts`, I can't use it with `instanceof`. The following code doesn't seem to work, I guess because TS doesn't "know" that being an instance of `jQuery` means being "an instance" of `JQuery` interface.

```
var stringOrJQuery: string | JQuery;
...
if (stringOrJQuery instanceof jQuery) {
  ...
  // here stringOrJQuery is still string | JQuery
  ...
}
```

I'm using TS 2.0 beta.

Comment: can you check " typeof stringOrJQuery === 'string' "? Else - jQuery...

Comment: Have you tried the various solutions from here? [Check if object is a jQuery object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object)

Comment: @Liam: The first of the answers there is exactly what the OP is doing.

Comment: Yes but [there are others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25004941/542251).

Comment: @TSV good catch, indeed it works in that way :) I'll accept your answer if you post it, however the question in general can still have sense.

Comment: @Liam the problem is not the runtime check, but the compile time.

Comment: @Liam: Yes, but I think the thrust of the question is more "Why isn't this type safety check in TypeScript that should be working, working?"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the problem might be that the variable `jQuery` has the type `JQueryStatic` in the definition file, which is actually also correct.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In this context it doesn't make sense because `JQuery` is just an interface definition, hance it doesn't exist at runtime.

Comment: @ZoltánTamási: I figured something like that, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check string case:

```
if(typeof stringOrJQuery === 'string') {
    // string case
}
else {
    // jquery case case
}
```

Alternately, you can determine jQuery object by indirect checks like [the ones described in this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object), such as:

```
if(stringOrJQuery.jquery !== undefined) { ... // this is a jQuery object
```

the [`jquery` field](http://api.jquery.com/jquery-2/) of the jQuery object contains jQuery version and should be defined.