# TypeError: blur is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, blur

In my JQuery UI autocomplete function, I use `.blur()` to close IOS keyboard when a selection is made:

```
// Purpose: Instantiate Autocomplete
    function autocomplete() {
        searchInput.autocomplete({
            source: autocompleteCourts,
            minLength: 3,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                location.hash = "trigger-header";
                isEFile(event, ui);

                // Close keyboard on IOS when an option is selected
                ui.blur();
            }, open: function (event, ui) {
                $("li.ui-menu-item:odd").addClass("ui-menu-item-alternate");
                $(".ui-menu-item-alternate").css("background-color", "#f2f4f7");
                $("ul.ui-menu").addClass("mt-2 w-auto");
                $("ul.ui-menu").css("z-index", 0);
            }
        });
```

The browser is throwing the error `Uncaught TypeError: ui.blur is not a function`.

Should I check if the function `blur()` exists before calling it?

Comment: Are you loading your Javascript code before or after the page loads?

Comment: `ui = An Object with label and value properties for the selected option.`  It's not the actual input,  you could maybe try `event.currentTarget.blur()`

Comment: @merkur0 I have everything wrapped in a `$(document).ready();`

Comment: Have you confirmed that `ui` is an element?

Comment: @Lewis it may not be an element. What's a good way to verify? `console.log(ui);`?

Comment: There's a nice answer to that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853223/check-if-object-is-a-jquery-object). I believe blur() is only assigned to elements, and will be undefined on anything else.

Comment: `blur()` is a jQuery method, so try `$(ui).blur()`.

Comment: @Barmar Let me give that a shot. See if the error goes away. Not sure if I can test it because I don't have a physical iPad to go look at it

Comment: @Barmar Just tried it, and the error went away. I'd be curious if the keypad closes on IOS... unfortunately the emulator in Chrome won't replicate the keypad, so I'm s**t out of luck until I get a hold of my buddies iPad

Comment: @Barmar If you want to write that out as an answer. I will accept it and then I'll come back and update if it didn't work. Want you to get the credit at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ui` is the DOM element that the autoComplete is attached to, not the jQuery object. You need to call `jQuery()` in order to call methods like `.blur()`. So change

```
ui.blur();
```

to

```
$(ui).blur();
```

This is pretty common throughout jQuery -- callbacks generally receive DOM elements rather than the jQuery wrapper objects. E.g. when you use `.each()`, the second argument to the callback function is the DOM element.

Comment: Can also use `$(this).blur();`.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without jquery in React Native? I am using this ```fieldRef.current?.blur();``` and I get an error that ```TypeError: _fieldRef$current.blur is not a function```. This was my original problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63757905/property-blur-does-not-exist-on-type-input @Twisty

Comment: See https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/from-jquery-to-javascript-a-reference--net-23703 for translating jQuery to vanilla JS.